# PHP WAMP install php_tidy

Tags: php, wampserver

i have installed on my computer `WAMP` with `PHP 5.2.9-2`. I want to install `php_tidy` and i have read some tuts over the internet and i found out that i have to uncomment this `extension=php_tidy.dll` in php.ini, the problem is that i can't find that line.

Comment: Are you 100% sure you are editing the correct php.ini? It should be there, Tidy is bundled with PHP >= 5.

Comment: that's what i have read too, but...is not there >:) anyway...i solved it like @seengee said

Answer (score 4, accepted):

assuming you are on Wampserver 2.0 you just need to click on the Wampserver icon in your system tray, then go PHP > PHP extensions and click on php_tidy